# Scroll parent page to top from within iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to scroll to the top of a parent page from within an iFrame, but its not in the same domain.  It throws an "Unsafe JavaScript Attempt" when I try to do it with JavaScript.  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be found using the easyxdm libraries from http://easyxdm.net/wp/ to send the instruction to the parent.

Sorry I don't have the exact code.